# Github pages not showing images inside my div

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I created a new repo and uploaded all the files  but the images in my div id="Container" inside my index files are not showing up. [https://github.com/hkhan194/tres-chic/tree/gh-pages](https://github.com/hkhan194/tres-chic/blob/gh-pages/index.html)

I looked into all other questions regarding this matter and tried them but still no image showing.

Comment: GitHub is a platform to upload the code, it will not "run" your code. Instead, if you are using Markdown , then you can do stuff like uploading a image in the markup. Hope that helps!!

Comment: @Hkhan...just checking the images. I doubt the image file might be corrupted. Tried accessing the image url path  https://github.com/hkhan194/tres-chic/blob/gh-pages/img/brands/burberry.jpg. It doesnt display the image itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hkhan I have tried the link in IE and Google Chrome,

**In IE:**

Your website is working fine, the images are getting displayed.

**In Google Chrome:**

The images are not getting displayed and when i checked the console ,I am getting this error

**Error**:
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://hkhan194.github.io/tres-chic/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mixitup/latest/jquery.mixitup.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

**Solution**:

- It seems that Google chrome is not allowing acceptance of the script from the url you have mentioned for the JS.
- So the "mixItUp is not a function" error is getting thrown since the mixItUp function is from the former JS file.
- So you could save that javascript file as "jquery.mixitup.min.js" in your github in a specific path and then include the javascript in the  tag in your index file as shown below,

`<script src="Your path/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>`

Comment: In addition to this, you could use a `https://` CDN connection instead to prevent the Mixed Content error.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this isn't really a GitHub pages question. GitHub pages simply hosts your files. This is really a question about the HTML.

Secondly, you'll have much better luck if you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In your case this would be a smaller test page that only displays a single image.

That being said, I recommend going to the resulting HTML file: https://hkhan194.github.io/tres-chic/

Right-click anywhere in that page, and then go to "Inspect Element". That will open up a window that lets you explore the page elements, see any errors you're getting, and see what's going on over the network. I'm using Chrome, but every browser should have something very similar.

On the Network tab, notice that some of your image files aren't being found. These seem to be the result of misspellings: `JPG` or `jpeg` instead of `jpg`, that kind of thing.

Then on the Elements tab, find your products grid. Notice that its height is `0`, which doesn't seem right. Then go into the `div class="mix category-*"` tags and notice that they all have a `display` of `none`!

The problem is that your CSS is setting `#Container .mix` to `display:none`, which is going to prevent them from being shown.

Please try to get into the habit of exploring your page using this window, and try to understand the difference between what GitHub Pages is doing and what your HTML is doing. If you have further questions, please try to narrow your problem down to a smaller example page. Good luck.

Comment: thank you for your thoughts i did inspect the network and elements on the page using inspect before. The reason disply:none is to hide the images for filtering when a button is clicked here is the page running on a different hosting service http://emporium-stylist.com/index.html (dont mind the url haha)